# Hartford Police Incidents datasets -API to get complete data

Tags: api, socrata, soda, alteryx

I am an analytics student and wanted to work on a live dashboard. With the help of below API end point, I was able to build a sample dashboard. But the total rows being returned is just 1000. The dataset actually has almost 50k rows

https://data.hartford.gov/resource/889t-nwfu.json

But I want the complete dataset as an input. How should i go about it ?

Comment: We can't debug your code to determine why only 1000 rows are returned, because your code is not included here in your question. We should not have to leave this site in order to determine what you're asking. Please [edit] your question to include the *relevant* code here in the post itself

Answer (score 2):

The Socrata dev api has a default limit of 1000 records.  If you want more, you need to set the limit higher and probably implement some paging:

http://dev.socrata.com/docs/paging.html